# Getting (404 - File or directory not found) running site. in Umbraco 6

Tags: caching, razor, http-status-code-404, umbraco, umbraco6

Surprisingly I am getting 404 error message while navigating to pages.
And when I re-publish that particular page, it get start rendering , but again when I try to access it using direct url (Eg. http://SiteName/PageName.aspx) it again gives 404 error.
But when I access home page any time it get rendered.

I have tried the following

1)  I have cleared cache (By manually Deleted AppData/ Temp & Config files)

2)  Have re-publish entire site.

But not able to resolve it .

Kindly Guide me.
I am using using V6+

I use razor can it be it's cache issue , or any other hint so I can start drilling in that direction ?

Thank in Advance. :)

Comment: Have you touched the web.config? Do you have a template for your page?

Comment: Thanks , Found the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have re-structured the content tree (moved respective page under root node)

And Have done following changes to /config/404handlers.config

```
<NotFoundHandlers>
  <notFound assembly="Sample" type="HandleMySpecialUrls" />
  <notFound assembly="umbraco" type="handle404" last="true" />
</NotFoundHandlers>
```

Ref. http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-2549

[view Detail Post https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/72917-getting-404-file-or-directory-not-found-running-site#comment-234136](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/razor/72917-getting-404-file-or-directory-not-found-running-site#comment-234136)